# Using the cURL output

Tags: php, curl, twitter-streaming-api

I'm planning to record the live tweets on a particular topic. For the same, I'm using the twitter stream API with cURL in PHP.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?         track=SEARCH_PARAMETER');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$jsonOBJ = json_decode ($result);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($jsonOBJ);
?>
```

My problem is, if I set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to 0, I can see the tweets on the terminal. But I'm not able to store in the variable $jsonOBJ and print it.

Please Help!

Comment: wouldn't be easier to use and sdk for php with oauth?

Comment: Print out $result to see what it looks like before you try to decode it.

Comment: Now, I'm directly doing this " echo $result; ".
But nothing shows up on executing this script.

Comment: You are trying to decode results that may reach 10000 or over 125MB data as result .... you should use `stream` not curl

Comment: @Baba I have added "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);" such that I get limited amount of data and kill the cURL operation. But still there is no data stored in the variable.

And thanks for your suggestion. I will look into 'stream'

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**:  See new code at the end of the message, this was actually pretty easy to do with cURL but I went about it incorrectly the first time.

I wasn't able to get the Twitter stream API to work using cURL in conjunction with a `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` but have had success using [fsockopen()](http://php.net/fsockopen) and `fread()`.  I'm not sure why the readfunction wasn't working as I have used it before with success, but it must have something to do with the fact that the response data is "streaming" and is not sent using HTTP chunked encoding.  Essentially, my read function never got called so I couldn't process the data.

The method I used that is working now:

- Connect using fsockopen to `ssl://stream.twitter.com`
- Issue the basic HTTP request for stream data using `fputs`
- Consume the HTTP response headers and make sure there were no errors
- Read an amount data using `fread` in an infinite loop
- Each time a chunk of data is read, I call an internal buffer function
- The buffer function appends the new data to a buffer
- Buffer function then tries to process all messages in the buffer (if we have 1 or more complete messages)
- As it processes each message, the buffer is reduced until it is empty and then the function returns and data is read again

I've had it running for a couple of hours now and haven't had a dropped connection and I've processed over 30,000 messages with no errors yet.

Basically I implemented a callback system so that each time a full message is read from the buffer, it calls the user-defined callback with the json message so the application can do whatever it needs to do with the message (e.g. insert to database).

I don't have any short snippets to post here yet, but if you want, message me by going to the website listed on my profile and filling in the contact form and I'd be happy to share.  Maybe we can work together if anyone is interested.  I only did this for fun, I have no interest in Twitter and am not using it for financial reasons.  I'll put it on GitHub eventually perhaps.

*EDIT:*

Here is some cURL code that will connect to the streaming API and pass the JSON messages to a callback function as they are available.  This example uses gzip encoding to save bandwidth.

```
<?php

$USERNAME = 'youruser';
$PASSWORD = 'yourpass';
$QUERY    = 'nike';

/**
 * Called every time a chunk of data is read, this will be a json encoded message
 * 
 * @param resource $handle The curl handle
 * @param string   $data   The data chunk (json message)
 */
function writeCallback($handle, $data)
{
    /*
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    echo $data;
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    */

    $json = json_decode($data);
    if (isset($json->user) && isset($json->text)) {
        echo "@{$json->user->screen_name}: {$json->text}\n\n";
    }

    return strlen($data);
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=' . urlencode($QUERY));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'writeCallback');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); // disconnect after 20 seconds for testing
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  // debugging
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  'gzip, deflate'); // req'd to get gzip
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'tstreamer/1.0'); // req'd to get gzip

curl_exec($ch); // commence streaming

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

var_dump($info);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.
For now, I found a work around by using search twitter API.
I'll surely contact you when I take up streaming API again.

Comment: @Rubie_Newbie I added a working example of the streaming API using cURL.  I also have a working version in C#.  This php class [phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose/) may be of interest to you as well, though it doesn't support gzip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same kind of thing as well :) The problem is that when you do it in terminal, it's a stream, so the connection stays alive until you kill it. (ie the curl_exec() doesn't finish)

Try looking at CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION and CURLOPT_READFUNCTION. They might give you some hints.

Comment: I have added "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);" to kill curl_exec(). But still there is no data stored in the variable.

Comment: Are there tweets tweeted in that 30 seconds?

Comment: Yes. I can see them by printing it out to the terminal.

Comment: To be honest I'm trying to solve the same problem. The thing is we can't connect every 30 second to twitter, they'll block us. We need to have a connection open to them as long as we intend to read the stream. So it probably has to be run in the background write it to another stream and the web page read that second stream.... or there might be an easier way that I haven't thought of of.

Answer (score 1):

@Reza Sanaie and others who may find this helpful.

I used the SEARCH TWITTER API and get the live tweets as well. So this could be helpful. 
Here is the code:

```
<?php
$query = "SEARCH_PARAMETER";
$request = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=".urlencode($query);
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$jsonobj = json_decode($response);
 print_r($jsonobj);
?>
```

I also have the MySQL connection setup to push it into the database and this script is added in the crontab to automate the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Am just rushing you an answer as leaving for the day. That looks like it should work.

Below is a function I use where I pass it a URL and some XML data and it returns an associative array saying true or false for success and the retuen value as a string.

```
function do_curl($url, $data)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);

    $curl_return=array();

    if (!is_string($result))
        {
        $curl_return['STATUS'] = FALSE;
        $curl_return['ERRMSG'] = curl_error($ch);
        }
    else
        {
        $curl_return['STATUS'] = TRUE;
        $curl_return['RESPONSE'] = $result;
        }
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $curl_return;
    }
```